# When I downcast UIView to SKView, I get an exception

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, casting, sprite-kit

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: [], animations: ({

        self.background.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.PlayButton.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.infoButton.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.logo.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.infoHidden.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.settingsButton.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.shareButton.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        //self.adBanner.center.x = self.view.frame.width + 600
        self.view.frame.width + 800

    }), completion: nil)

    let View2 = self.view as! SKView        // View
    View2.ignoresSiblingOrder = false       // Perfomance
    let Play = GameScene()                  // Game
    Play.scaleMode = .ResizeFill            // Scale
    View2.presentScene(Play)                // Present
```

Why does this code return the exception "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1f1ed90) to 'SKView'"? That code was working earlier, and all of a sudden it starts throwing an exception. My View's class IS set to SKView in the storyboard. The weird thing is that this exception only started throwing itself when I implemented iad into my game. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this thread](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=21041) will help you, specifically this quote

> SKView is a subclass of UIView. The UIViewController's view can be any
>   kind of UIView object, it doesn't have to specifically be a UIView
>   object.
>
> Note that this code could still fail at runtime if the view wasn't an
>   SKView (e.g. if it actually was a UIView object), so you have to be
>   sure.

The main point being, your UIView that you are down casting probably is not a SKView, but rather a UIView so you are getting a runtime exception. try using an optional downcast as? and handle the situation where the downcast fails.